# insert trigger insert value back

Tags: triggers, sqlite

I want to create a trigger on an insert action. This trigger should fire when a new row of clients is created. The trigger should create a new row in the accounts table and then insert the key value back into the row that fired the trigger.

```
clients:
_id|firstname|lastname|accountnr

accounts:
accountnr|balance
```

I tried creating a trigger with one insert and one update statement. The insert creates a new account in the account table. The problem is that the account table uses autoincrement, so I do not know the value of the newly created accountnr. That value I need to know in the update statement to update the accountnr of the people table to the accountnr in the account table.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried creating a trigger with one insert and one update statement. The insert creates a new account in the account table. The problem is that the account table uses autoincrement, so I do not know the value of the newly created accountnr. That value I need to know in the update statement to update the accountnr of the people table to the accountnr in the account table

Answer (score 2):

That's what [last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) is for:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_account_for_new_client
AFTER INSERT ON clients
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.accountnr IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO accounts(balance)
    VALUES(0);

    UPDATE clients
    SET accountnr = last_insert_rowid()
    WHERE _id = NEW._id;
END;
```